# How to reset RectTransform's position?

Tags: unity, gui

So, I am trying to make a simple GUI Instantiate system. The GUI is going to spawn successfully, but the position is wrong.

```
Position : (Left, Right: 249.8423 ; Top, Bottom : 400) 
Anchors : (Min: X:0 Y:0 ; Max: X:1 Y:1) 
Pivots : (X:0.5 Y:0.5) 
Rotation : (X:0 Y:0 Z:0)
Scale : (X:1 Y:1 Z:1) always...
```

My Code :

```
    GUIPausePopup pause = UI.Create<GUIPausePopup>(GameObject.Find("Canvas"));
    //Spawn and set parent(Canvas)
    pause.GetComponent<Transform>().gameObject.SetActive(true);
    //Working without any issues.


    //Position system not work. I don't know why.
    pause.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition3D = new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f);
    pause.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition = new Vector2(0f, 0f);
    pause.GetComponent<RectTransform>().localPosition = new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f);
    pause.GetComponent<RectTransform>().position = new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f);
    pause.transform.position = new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f);
    pause.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f);
```

Thanks for help...

Comment: Unity UI layouting problems are notoriously hard to troubleshoot without a complete picture of everything that is happening in the UI... Are there any layout-related components on the object or one of its parents?

Comment: pretty sure you need to set anchorMin and anchorMax before seeting anchoredPosition.

Comment: I'm having this same issue... 4 years later x_x

Answer (score 1):

4 years later but I bring an answer that solved it for me.

This is using a World Space Canvas and I was trying to instantiate a prefab (menu)

```
menu.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition3D = this.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition3D;
```

"this" being the parent

I think what was messing it up for me was that since I'd been at this for a while I tried the same thing you did: after calling this I had other things trying to reset it's position and those were the ones causing issues! Just do anchoredPosition3D and nothing else and it should work - if your situation was like mine.

**EDIT**:
As @DMGregory explains in the comments the correct way would be:

```
((RectTransform)(menu.transform))anchoredPosition3D
   = ((RectTransform)transform).anchoredPosition3D;
```

But one year ago the code that I included here worked for me.